# Hide image tag odoo 9

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

On front end of page I use img tag for display binary image from database.

```xml
<img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % task.image" />
```

How hide tag if value is empty, now in my solution display small square.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un8fV.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```xml
<t t-if="task.image">
    <img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % task.image"/>
</t>
```